# Handling url "/foobar/" replaces css <link>, and js <script> path beginnings with "/foobar/"

Tags: go

I'm trying to use the standard Go http package for my router.

In my main.go it starts:

```
func main() {
    mux := http.NewServeMux()

    fs := http.FileServer(http.Dir("static"))
    handler := http.StripPrefix("/static/", fs)
    mux.Handle("/static/", handler)

    mux.HandleFunc("/my-example-url/", FooHandler)
}
```

inside FooHandler() I have some println()

```
func FooHandler(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    println("r.URL.Path->",r.URL.Path)
    //more business logic
}

// output:

r.URL.Path-> /my-example-url/static/css/normalize.css
r.URL.Path-> /my-example-url/static/libs/xss.js
```

So the initial part of url should NOT be there (the /my-example-url/ part)

I think this only happends when I'm trying to serve an endpoint with trailing slash such as:

```
mux.Handle("/my-example-url/", handler)
```

My end goal is to get some resource based on the id I'm trying to pass in the url after the trailing slash for example:

```
http://localhost:3001/my-example-url/bb98610
```

Comment: It does not replace anything, you're requesting those urls

Comment: Handle Static File correctly: https://dev.to/hauxe/golang-http-serve-static-files-correctly-2oj2

Comment: Show the html that is making those requests, but most probably you are using relative paths instead of absolute ones which causes the browser to append that relative path to the path already in the location bar. i.e. `<link href="static/css/normalize.css" rel="stylesheet">` is turned, by the browser, into `/my-example-url/static/css/normalize.css`. use `<link href="/static/css/normalize.css" rel="stylesheet">` instead (*note the leading slash*).

Comment: @mkopriva WOW that was the problem pls post this as answer so I can accept :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the html file, the one that's triggering the requests for the static resources, you are most probably using relative paths instead of absolute ones which causes the browser to append that relative path to the path already in the location bar.

For example:

```
<link href="static/css/normalize.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

will be turned, by the browser, into `/my-example-url/static/css/normalize.css`.

Instead you want to use *(note the leading slash)*:

```
<link href="/static/css/normalize.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

Comment: I really appreciate your help, Will read more into absolute and relative paths have a good day!